# Extracting the MAX value from a Naive Bayes Classifier

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am applying NB and NLTK to classify phrases according to some feelings, like sadness, fear, happyness etc..

`classificador = nltk.NaiveBayesClassifier.train(base_completa_treinamento)`

and applying this function to a phrase:

```
def avalia(teste):
    #teste = 'Pqp, que trânsito chato da porra!'
    testeStemming = []
    stemmer = nltk.stem.RSLPStemmer()
    for (palavras_treinamento) in teste.split():
        comStem = [p for p in palavras_treinamento.split()]
        testeStemming.append(str(stemmer.stem(comStem[0])))

    novo = extrator_palavras(testeStemming)
    distribuicao = classificador.prob_classify(novo)
    for classe in distribuicao.samples():
        print('%s: %f' % (classe, (distribuicao.prob(classe))))
```

like this:

`avalia('he died')`

and get this as result:

```
alegria: 0.117609
nojo: 0.050533
medo: 0.207932
raiva: 0.226550
surpresa: 0.045293
tristeza: 0.352083
```

How do i change the function avalia() to show only the highest value ('tristeza:0.35')?  I tried to sue max function but didnt work.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of this part:

```
for classe in distribuicao.samples():
    print('%s: %f' % (classe, (distribuicao.prob(classe))))
```

Try this way

```
classe_array = [(classe, (distribuicao.prob(classe))) for classe in distribuicao.samples()]
inverse = [(value, key) for key, value in classe_array]
max_key = max(inverse)[1]
for each in classe_array:
   if each[0] == max_key:
      print(each)
```

Comment: Nice !! works like a charm !  Thanks my friend !